# Evaluating performance of Generative Adverserial Network?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, gan, generative-models

What is the best way to evaluate performance of Generative Adverserial Network (GAN)? Perhaps measuring the distance between two distributions or maybe something else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it depends on what exactly you're doing with the GANs. If you're generating images, the two most popular (to my knowledge) are the Inception Score [[1]](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1606.03498.pdf) and Frechet Inception Distance [[2]](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1706.08500.pdf). GANs aren't my direct area of study, but I don't think you can miss starting with those two.

Actually, [Goodfellow himself endorsed FID](https://twitter.com/goodfellow_ian/status/932732571019911168?lang=en) (a year ago) on twitter, so I'd start there.